# PHP Script not respect greater than symbol (>) when write in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a game developed in Scirra Construct 2 that saves scores in a database.
To submit the scores to the database using AJAX, and the hosting of the receive PHP files .
The PHP checks if the score is sent greater score in the existing database , and if greater , stores , and if less discards .

The game works well , keep the scores are higher every time , but I have a problem.
If I close the game and I open omits the previous score and overwritten by the new being even lower.

It seems that everything resets to write again , but does not respect the saved score above.

For example:

If in the first run i get 25 points, after 75 points, the last value saved in DB is 75 because is greater than 25.

If after i close the game and run again, if the first try i get 25, normally the game should to conserve the 75 points, but in this case ocurrs a error and the 75 points are changed for the 25 points, still if 25 < 75.

What's going on?

This is the PHP

[img]https://i.gyazo.com/6650fa313895fa1ffceb87dd2f1a8ebd.png[/img]
[img]https://i.gyazo.com/844b2c2fadce1b85cf7b5cd3d8e36678.png[/img]

Is writed in spanish.

The parameters U, PM, PS, PR PM, PT, are sent by AJAX in the normal way (with request URL etc....) example:

Request "URL/updatescore.php?U="& IDUser & "&PS=" & Score

Any error in the PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: don't post pictures of the code, post the code itself

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your posted code that compares to the actual values that are stored in the database.
Where do your variables get their initial values from? Do you query the database first? Hard to tell because you haven't shown all your code.

If you close the game and open it and the variables are not retrieved from somewhere then they would not have any initial values and would thus be empty strings.

Comment: The PHP read the actual value stored in DB with a SELECT Query, after obtain a value from the game through AJAX (AJAX send a score into a char example P, and the PHP receive this char and then compare with read value in DB. If char value is greater than value in DB, is updated.

this image show how send the score to php

[img]https://i.gyazo.com/7ee28e0b8dc8f938ffe3609be0c07447.png[/img]